# How do I know if NotebookLocate did not find the cell tag?

Tags: notebooks

Is there a way to programmatically detect whether or not `NotebookLocate[{"file", "cell tag"}]` has found the cell? And then if not found, stay at current selection instead of jumping to the end of the notebook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

my solution (but I have limited skill)  would be to first check if the tag you were looking for was in the list of the notebook's cell tags...

```
nb=InputNotebook[];
NotebookTools`NotebookCellTags[nb]
```

If not, then don't bother looking in the first place...?

So create your own "notebook locate"  that checks if the tag in question is a member of the cell tag list, and if so, then call NotebookLocate

Comment: I think it's worth adding that `NotebookTools` is an undocumented package. This answer confused me for a bit, until I figured that out.